Default GCP IAM roles from Firebase
So, I've created project on Firebase, that uses Cloud Function. Since I am using some additional Google Cloud services, I needed to add Roles to some of my IAM accounts.
I've added it, and it worked - great. However, I am lacking the understanding of different roles that are generated by default when creating Firebase project. I have the following:

{projectId}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
firebase-adminsdk-bjiqq@some-project-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com  
some-project-prod@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
myemail@email.com

Can anyone explain of point me to the right direction? I was not able to find any resources that explain in details what all of those IAM accounts do.
